# python-textFSM parse multiple line

Tags: python-textfsm

i have to parse an isis database and i have pb to capture some metrics.

My templates is :

```
Value Required LSPID (.*\.\d+\-00)
Value OVERLOAD_BIT ([0,1])
Value HOSTNAME (.*)
Value IPADD (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
Value List CONNECTED_METRIC (\d+)
Value List LSPID_PEER (.*)
Value List SUBNET_METRIC (\d+)
Value List SUBNET (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\/\d+)

Start
        ^${LSPID}.*[0,1]/[0,1]/${OVERLOAD_BIT}
        ^\s+Hostname:\s+${HOSTNAME}
        ^\s+IP\s+Address:\s+${IPADD} -> Metrics

Metrics
        ^\s+Metric:\s+${CONNECTED_METRIC}\s+IS-Extended\s+${LSPID_PEER}
        ^\s+Metric:\s+${SUBNET_METRIC}\s+IP\s+${SUBNET} -> Record Start
```

My datas to parse are :

```
ROUTER_A.00-00  0x00020850   0xE97D        1122              0/0/0
  Area Address: 49.0001
  NLPID:        0xCC 
  Hostname: ROUTER_A
  IP Address:   172.17.32.2
  Metric: 1000       IS-Extended ROUTER_D.00
  Metric: 100        IS-Extended ROUTER_E.00
  Metric: 100        IS-Extended ROUTER_F.00
  Metric: 1          IP 172.17.32.2/32
  Metric: 1          IP 172.25.9.142/32
ROUTER_B.00-00       0x00064747   0x27E9        1183              0/0/0
  Area Address: 49
  NLPID:        0xCC 
  Hostname: ROUTER_B
  Metric: 1000000    IS-Extended ROUTER_G.00
  Metric: 1000000    IS-Extended ROUTER_H.00
  IP Address:   192.168.12.51
  Metric: 0          IP 172.25.92.155/32
  Metric: 0          IP 192.168.12.51/32
ROUTER_C.00-00    0x0006B0C0   0x4632        1113              0/0/1
  Area Address: 49.0001
  NLPID:        0xCC 
  Hostname: ROUTER_C
  Router ID:    192.168.128.131
  IP Address:   172.25.92.62
  Metric: 10000      IS-Extended ROUTER_I.00
  Metric: 50000      IS-Extended ROUTER_J.00
  Metric: 1          IP 172.25.92.62/32
  Metric: 1          IP 192.168.128.131/32
ROUTER_K.00-00  0x00020850   0xE97D        1122              0/0/0
  Area Address: 49.0001
  NLPID:        0xCC 
  Hostname: ROUTER_K
  IP Address:   172.17.72.2
  Metric: 1000       IS-Extended ROUTER_D.00
  Metric: 100        IS-Extended ROUTER_E.00
  Metric: 100        IS-Extended ROUTER_F.00
```

And i have this result :

```
['ROUTER_A.00-00', '0', 'ROUTER_A', '172.17.32.2', ['1000', '100', '100'], ['ROUTER_D.00', 'ROUTER_E.00', 'ROUTER_F.00'], ['1'], ['172.17.32.2/32']]
['ROUTER_B.00-00', '0', 'ROUTER_B', '192.168.12.51', ['1000000', '1000000'], ['ROUTER_G.00', 'ROUTER_H.00'], ['0'], ['172.25.92.155/32']]
['ROUTER_C.00-00', '1', 'ROUTER_C', '172.25.92.62', ['10000', '50000'], ['ROUTER_I.00', 'ROUTER_J.00'], ['1'], ['172.25.92.62/32']]
['ROUTER_K.00-00', '0', 'ROUTER_K', '172.17.72.2', ['1000', '100', '100'], ['ROUTER_D.00', 'ROUTER_E.00', 'ROUTER_F.00'], [], []]
```

We can see that only the first "ip metric" are parsed (no parse for ip address 172.25.9.142/32 by example).
Could you help me to find what is wrong ?

Answer (score -1):

I made a workaround :
i have edited the data file and inserted a tag that i match in fsm template.

So now i have this template and it's working fine but if someone has the solution to avoid to edit the source file it will be smarter than this workaround:

```
Value Required LSPID (.*\.\d+\-00)
Value OVERLOAD_BIT ([0,1])
Value HOSTNAME (.*)
Value IPADD (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
Value List CONNECTED_METRIC (\d+)
Value List LSPID_PEER (.*)
Value List SUBNET_METRIC (\d+)
Value List SUBNET (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\/\d+)
Value END_LSPID (END_LSPID)

Start
        ^${LSPID}.*[0,1]/[0,1]/${OVERLOAD_BIT}
        ^\s+Hostname:\s+${HOSTNAME}
        ^\s+IP\s+Address:\s+${IPADD} -> Metrics

Metrics
        ^\s+Metric:\s+${CONNECTED_METRIC}\s+IS-Extended\s+${LSPID_PEER}
        ^\s+Metric:\s+${SUBNET_METRIC}\s+IP\s+${SUBNET}
        ^${END_LSPID} -> Record Start
```